# How to use AdMob Banner Ads in TableView in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob, ads

I want to show different ads between every 5 results in tableview
I have used admob banner ads in my ios project
Tableview shows same ads after every 5 results even I am using different ad unit id to load ad after every 5 rows.

Any solution to get different ads after 5 rows?

Answer (score 0):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath, set admob banner cell every 5 rows

like this

```
    switch(indexPath.row) {
       case 5, 10, 15...: // every 5 rows, put admob banner cell
           let cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"AdmobBannerTableViewCell"];
           return cell;
       case 1,... : // other rows...
           let cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"AnotherTableViewCell"];
           return cell;
    }
```